# How to make sure that string is valid

Tags: java

I'm parsing XML and for now I use `nodeTextValue.length() > 0` to check whether the nodeTextValue is valid string, but I'm having issues with `\n` `\r` and so on, preceding and following nodeText, is there an existing class to trim string on both ways not just after so it returns the valid string

I'm using stax

Comment: Are you *really* writing code to parse XML?  Or are making use of an existing XML parser and (for example) an existing DOM library?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[trim()](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) will remove leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: This sounds like what you're looking for, @London

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the trim function on strings. I would also recommend googling Java regular expressions for validating strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
!nodeTextValue().trim().equals("").
```